# how can send tcp packet with golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn more about how a game connection works,
and I used wireshark to know the first packet that is sent when I connect to the server.
I'm trying to understand what this package would be and how to send it

this is the packet:

```
// 0000   5c 64 7a df a9 51 c8 7f 54 04 ca 09 08 00 45 00
// 0010   00 34 48 49 40 00 80 06 04 a4 c0 a8 00 68 c0 63
// 0020   2c 63 f7 0b 08 3a a0 55 b5 9c 00 00 00 00 80 02
// 0030   fa f0 71 10 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01
// 0040   04 02
```

but I can't figure out how to transform this wireshark return into byte arrays

my code:

```
package main

import (
    "net"

    "github.com/aerogo/packet"
)

func main() {
    conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "x.x.x.x")

    stream := packet.NewStream(1024)
    stream.SetConnection(conn)

    // Send a message
    stream.Outgoing <- packet.New(1, []byte{}) // How can I send this package

    // Receive message
    msg := <-stream.Incoming
}
```

Comment: `[]byte{0x5c, 0x64, 0x7a... }` ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/NfGYO5CigbP)). However the library you are using (`github.com/aerogo/packet`) sends extra info (packet type, length) which may not be appropriate (you could just call [`Write`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Conn)).. In terms of working out what the data in the packet means; that can be tricky to reverse engineer and probably off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Golang to compose raw TCP packet (using gopacket) and send it via raw socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218989/how-to-use-golang-to-compose-raw-tcp-packet-using-gopacket-and-send-it-via-raw)

Comment: @Brits Thank you, could you tell me how I can go from hex to bytes? How did you do 0x5c, etc?

is only put 0x at the beginning of the hex?

with hex is 00 will it become 0x00 ?

Comment: See the [language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Integer_literals).`"0" ( "x" | "X" ) [ "_" ] hex_digits` is how you state a hex literal (and, yes, I just added `0x`). Realistically you may want to load the data from a file.